# Why do we have to conform both UIViewController and UITableViewDataSource?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently, I want to have a separated class for data only. However, I cannot just declare a class like this:

```
class DataSource: UITableViewDataSource
```

It would give me a lot of error. And, I have to do this instead:

```
class DataSource: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource
```

So, why? I come from Java background, so I don't understand why I have to implement A to implement B. I tried reading the official documents from Apple, but I could not find the answer.

Edit: here is the error:

```
Type 'DataSource' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'
Type 'DataSource' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'
```

and, XCode suggests a solution to fix it is to add "@objc " at the beginning of the override function. The error still there after the fix though.

Edit 2: I am aware that I need to implement 2 functions for the data source to work. However, it will not work without implementing UIViewController.

[image]

It will work after adding UIViewController!

[image]

Comment: What errors?   Should I guess?

Comment: Just added the error

Comment: you need to insert datasource methods i.e numberOfRows, cellForRows etc

Comment: No, you have to have UIViewController. The override functions alone will not work.

Comment: Please provide your complete implementation of DataSource with just UITableViewDataSource, the required methods, and the error and the line on which it occurs.

Comment: Just edited the post.

Comment: Please check my answer below, hope it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Protocol `UITableViewDataSource` comes from `NSObjectProtocol`. So you have to make your class inherit from NSObject to conform to the `NSObjectProtocol`. Vanilla Swift classes do not. But many parts of UIKit expect NSObjects. And you have to implement the required methods of this protocol. Try below code:

```
class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```